# Add Javascript with 'id' attribute?

Tags: javascript

I've been asked to add the following to a page :

```
<script id="dsxc_script" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.docserver1.co.uk/dsxc/client.js?acc=xx&integrated=true"></script>
```

However I don't think the drupal_add_js() function will allow me to set an 'id' attribute.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Seems Drupal does not have support for id built-in. If needed, hacking it directly into html.tpl.php is a way, byt it does not seem to be a really good way.

Comment: Also replace `&` with `&amp;` in link.

Answer (score 7):

drupal_add_js does not support an ID attribute as it seems. 
However, as a workaround, you can use drupal_add_html_head to add stuff to the head section.

Ex:

```
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'script',
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'src' => 'https://www.docserver1.co.uk/dsxc/client.js?acc=xx&integrated=true',
    'type' => 'text/javascript',
    'id' => 'dsxc_script',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'dsxc');


//dpm(drupal_render($element)); Gives the following:
// <script src="https://www.docserver1.co.uk/dsxc/client.js?acc=xx&amp;integrated=true" type="text/javascript" id="dsxc_script" />
```

You can always embed these scripts in your html.tpl.php file, but if you want to add the stuff conditionally, I think this will work.